# Query using objectGUID - Spring LDAP Template

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, hex

I am trying to fetch, store and in turn use objectGUID to query Active directory.
To get user attributes i am using following

```
public static class MyDnKeyValueAttMapper implements AttributesMapper<Object> {
        @Override
        public List<LdapKeyValueList> mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes)
                throws NamingException, javax.naming.NamingException {
            List<LdapKeyValueList> attributeKeyValMap = new ArrayList<LdapKeyValueList>();
            NamingEnumeration<String> namingEnumeration = attributes.getIDs();

            while (namingEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                String attributeName = (String) namingEnumeration.nextElement();
                String AttributeValue = attributes.get(attributeName).get().toString();
                attributeKeyValMap.add(new LdapKeyValueList(attributeName, AttributeValue));
            }
            return attributeKeyValMap;
        }
    }
```

objectGuid always seems to be returned in string format.
I have also tried -

```
UUID guid = (UUID) attributes.get("objectGUID").get();
```

This throws error of "cannot convert string to uuid"

Seems like before i can do anything ldaptemplate search always return attributes in string format.

How can i get hold of "objectGUID" in its format, so that i can store it and use in ldapTemplate search queries.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want a binary attribute (objectGUID has Octet String syntax) to be retrieved as a string, you must say so.  With Spring you'll have to add `<entry key="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary" value="objectGUID"/>` to your context environment.

Later on `byte[] guid = (byte[]) namingEnumeration.getAttributes().get("objectGUID").get();` should return what you're looking for.

Just typed, not tested.

Comment: Thank you, for other wondering how to achieve this - please consider following post - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/64997-trying-to-retrieve-binary-attrib-objectguid-from-activedirectory-using-usersearch

Answer (score 7):

for Spring, inject "java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary" prop into the ldapTemplate

```
@Bean
public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
  return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());
}

@Bean
public ContextSource contextSource() {
  final LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
  contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
  contextSource.setBase(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.base"));
  contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user"));
  contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));

  // Important!!! Tell ldapTemplate to retrieve AD field
  // "objectGUID" as binary. Otherwise it will be
  // retrieved as a String, thus, modifying the byte[] array
  final Map<String, Object> envProps = new HashMap<>();
  envProps.put("java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary","objectGUID");
  contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(envProps);

  return contextSource;
}
```

...

```
// Will not complain about the String to byte[] conversion and
// Has to be 16 in length. If not, you did something 
// wrong. For example ldapTemplate still retrieves objectGUID
// as String, modifying the value
byte[] guidBytes = (byte[]) attributes.get("objectGUID").get();
if (guidBytes.length == 16) {
  // Convert encoded AD objectGUID to UUID
  // objectGUID is not storing bits sequentially, so do the dance
  UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(
    String.format("%02x%02x%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x-%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", 
    guidBytes[3] & 255, 
    guidBytes[2] & 255, 
    guidBytes[1] & 255, 
    guidBytes[0] & 255, 
    guidBytes[5] & 255, 
    guidBytes[4] & 255, 
    guidBytes[7] & 255, 
    guidBytes[6] & 255, 
    guidBytes[8] & 255, 
    guidBytes[9] & 255, 
    guidBytes[10] & 255, 
    guidBytes[11] & 255, 
    guidBytes[12] & 255, 
    guidBytes[13] & 255, 
    guidBytes[14] & 255, 
    guidBytes[15] & 255));
}
```